# isItPrime using a boolean method? So Close

Tags: java

I feel I am so close! The output is just outputting true true true or false false false (depending on the length of the array and the user inputs.

I feel this is because of the if/else! For instance, if the number you input first is either true or false it makes all of them that!?

This is supposed to print to the console the numbers in the array, the index of the array numbers, and whether they are prime or not, individually.

Thanks for the help!!

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Arrays;
public class isItPrime {
//main method
public static void main (String[] args) {
//Scanner
  Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
  System.out.println("Enter length of array: ");
  int n = input.nextInt();
  int[] numbers = new int[n];
  System.out.println("Enter " + n +" integers to fill the array: ");
  for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
     numbers[i] = input.nextInt();
  }
  System.out.println(Arrays.toString(numbers));
  for(int j=0; j<n; j++){
     System.out.println(numbers[j] + ": " + j + " -- " + isPrime(numbers));
  }
}
public static boolean isPrime(int[] numbers){
  boolean Prime = true; //initial boolean value
  for (int i = 2; i<numbers.length; i++) {
     for (int j=0; j<numbers.length; j++) {
        if (numbers[j] == 1 || numbers[j] == 0) {
           Prime = false;
        }
        else if (numbers[j]%i==0){ //function which determines if an int is prime.
           Prime = false;    
        } 
        else {
           Prime = true;
        }
     }
  }
  return Prime;
 }
}
```

Comment: Why do you return prime? What do you want to return?

Comment: This is supposed to return to the console the array numbers, the index of that number, and whether they are prime or not @smttsp

Comment: I didnt get what you mean

Comment: Given the statement in main where you are printing out if a number is prime or not, it seems likely your isPrime method should take a single integer as a parameter (the value at the index j), and return a boolean.

Comment: @smttsp If I input an array 5 6 7, the console will print:
5: index(0) -- prime
6: index(1) -- not prime
7: index(2) -- prime

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you need:

```
public class IsItPrime{
 //main method

public static void main(String[] args) {
//Scanner
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter length of array: ");
    int n = input.nextInt();
    int[] numbers = new int[n];
    System.out.println("Enter " + n + " integers to fill the array: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        numbers[i] = input.nextInt();
    }
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(numbers));
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
        System.out.println(numbers[j] + ": " + j + " -- " + isPrime(numbers[j]));
    }
}

public static boolean isPrime(int numbers) {
    boolean Prime = true; 
    if (numbers == 1 || numbers == 0) {
        Prime = false;
        return Prime;
    }

    for (int i = 2; i < numbers; i++) {

        if (numbers % i == 0) {
            Prime = false;
            return Prime;
        } else {
            Prime = true;
        }

    }

    return Prime;
}
}
```

Only a single integer needs to be passed to the isPrime function.
Also, for processing this integer only a single loop would suffice in the isPrime function.
I have made the required changes.

Comment: Thank you so much, I have a simple request:

What is the easiest way for it to display "prime" instead of "true" and "not prime" instead of "false?"

Basically converting the boolean value to a string

Comment: Check the new answer. Made the required changes in the function

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to return which elements are prime:

```
public static boolean isPrime(int[] numbers){
    boolean prime[] = new boolean[numbers.length]; //initial boolean value
    for (int i = 0; i<numbers.length; i++) {
        for (int j=2; j<=sqrt(numbers[i]); j++) {
            if (numbers[j]%i==0){ //function which determines if an int is prime.
                prime[i] = false;
                continue;
            }
        }
        prime[i] = true
    }
    return prime;
}
```

I'm creating a prime array and whichever is prime, I'm making its position in the array true, and i continue with the next element.

Also, for prime, you have to check until `square root of the number` for the sake of efficiency.

For example, if you want to check if **10 is prime**, it is better to iterate until **sqrt(10)=3.2**.

Answer (score 0):

Your biggest problem is your `isPrime()` method should calculate if a *particular* number is prime, not analyse an *array* of numbers.

Try this:

```
public static boolean isPrime(int number){
    // return true if prime 
}
```

And call it like this:

```
 System.out.println(numbers[j] + ": " + j + " -- " + isPrime(number[j]));
```

Answer (score 0):

Altered method to return string i.e, "Prime" or "Not Prime".

```
public static String isPrime(int numbers) {
    if (numbers == 1 || numbers == 0) {
        return "Not Prime";
    }

    for (int i = 2; i < numbers; i++) {

        if (numbers % i == 0) {
            return "Not Prime";
        }

    }

    return "Prime";
}
```